# Using the java api for Elasticsearch how can I map the doc id during indexing

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am indexing data to an ElasticSearch engine server. I have a domain object called User.
Below is the relevant code I am using. Right now, the `_id` attribute in elasticsearch is set to the incremental value from this command as shown below:

```
bulkRequest.add(client.prepareIndex("heros", "entry", i+"")
```

But I don't want an arbitrary id incremented, because Wonder Woman will also have a SN_NO as the id for her document. How can I map this Domain object's unique ID (SN_NO) to the `_id` in the elasticsearch engine? The reason I want this is, I may have to change one of her attributes such as waist_size for example over time. And I don't want the elasticsearch engine containing 2 Wonder Women one with a thin waist and another one fat as a silly example.

Sorry for the long question, i tried hard to make it entertaining to read.

Thank you in advance!

public class TestBulkElastic {

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

    // Create User object
    User user1 = new User();
    user1.setGender(Gender.FEMALE);
    Name n = new Name();
    n.setFirst("Wonder");
    n.setLast("Woman");
    user1.setName(n);
    user1.setVerified(false);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.writeValue(new File("user.json"), user1);

    HashMap<String,Object> fileResult =
            new ObjectMapper().readValue(new File("user.json"), HashMap.class);

    Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
            .put("cluster.name", "MyES").build();

    Client client = new TransportClient(settings)
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("123.123.123.123", 9350));

    BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequest = client.prepareBulk();
    int batch = 10000;
    int i = 0 ;

    while(i < 10000000){
        bulkRequest.add(client.prepareIndex("heros", "entry", i+"")
            .setSource(fileResult));

        if(i%batch == 0){
            bulkRequest.execute().actionGet();
            bulkRequest = null;
            bulkRequest = client.prepareBulk();
            }

        i++;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please indent your code correctly, it's really hard to read like this...

Comment: Thanks. I have fixed the indentation. This code should compile properly as long as you have the libraries: User class is arbitrary that contains a nested class called Name so that I can experiment with nested jsons. Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: I have read your question several times and am struggling to understand it (though I haven't used the Java elasticsearch plugin). What is `SN_NO`? I can't see it in your code...

Comment: Why you no delete `i+""` code and use `SN_NO+""` instead? Am i missing something?

Comment: I am just providing SN_NO as an example. Lets say SN_NO is a unique identifier for every User , Super Woman, Bat Man etc.. each must have a SN_NO (Social Security number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the mapping for the type.
Set the path of the _id field to point to the field to be used as the _id

```
{
"YourType": {
    "dynamic": "true",
    "_id": {
        "path": "new_id"
    },
    "_timestamp": {
        "enabled": true,
        "store": true
    },
    "properties": {
        "new_id": {
            "type": "string",
            "fields": {
                "raw": {
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}